# Where can I find the following PopOut_Position() function?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to hunt down the `PopOut_Position` function. I just installed VS 2010 and 2008 and have grepped around, but am not having much luck.

I'm not sure if the following function is part of the ASP.NET Ajax Extensions, part of the regular ASP.NET installation or some custom component? Can anyone tell me where to find the actual source of it?

(found at http://www.treasury.gov/ScriptResource.axd?d=lD-SUtO2q-R1LQgmYXYpGl-wwM7o5wK7UhibeK85Ueeh_bBieNYAmz7vsBUeYkUqpBGKrIa74BYS07LvzOVeY_9RxcU_dlX_z8iEwyovrSmIZup7whXVznS1-ASrNR8B9jPhWw2&t=4f2d169d)

```
 function PopOut_Position(panel, hideScrollers) { 
      if (window.opera) { 
          panel.parentNode.removeChild(panel); 
          document.forms[0].appendChild(panel); 
      }
     ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/Menu.js

Comment: Sharing the link for posterity.